How mock Blob using jest and jest-fetch-mock
I am using React, and RTK Query and trying to write tests, checking correct downloading files, using jest and jest-fetch-mock.
test('should download correct file', async () => { 
 const text = '<template>some template</template>>'
 const testBlob = new Blob([text]);

 render(<DownloadButton/>);

 const mockedCreateObjectURL = jest.fn();
 const mockedRevokeObjectURL = jest.fn();
 global.URL.createObjectURL = mockedCreateObjectURL;
 global.URL.revokeObjectURL = mockedRevokeObjectURL;

  const buttonElem = screen.getByText('Download');
  await userEvent.click(buttonElem);

  expect(mockedCreateObjectURL).toBeCalled();
  expect(mockedCreateObjectURL).toBeCalledWith(testBlob);
})

Test success, but not correct, I can replace testBlob with another Blob, and will be a success test.
Also, I have an error in the console
A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `payload`. Value: Blob {
      [Symbol(type)]: 'application/octet-stream',
      [Symbol(buffer)]: <Buffer 5b 6f 62 6a 65 63 74 20 42 6c 6f 62 5d>
    } 
    Take a look at the logic that dispatched this action:  {
      type: 'rtkQueryApi/executeQuery/fulfilled',
      payload: Blob {
        [Symbol(type)]: 'application/octet-stream',
        [Symbol(buffer)]: <Buffer 5b 6f 62 6a 65 63 74 20 42 6c 6f 62 5d>
      },
      meta: {
        fulfilledTimeStamp: 1721133765208,
        baseQueryMeta: { request: [Request], response: [Response] },
        RTK_autoBatch: true,
        arg: {
          type: 'query',
          subscribe: true,
          forceRefetch: true,
          subscriptionOptions: [Object],
          endpointName: 'getTerminalGroupCertificatesConfig',
          originalArgs: 100,
          queryCacheKey: 'getTerminalGroupCertificatesConfig(100)',
          [Symbol(forceQueryFn)]: undefined
        },
        requestId: 'VJioDWBB5c0uoj69n4iMP',
        requestStatus: 'fulfilled'
      }
    } 

How to correct mock Blob response with jest-fetch-mock
Try to mock Blob's response with jest-fetch-mock, but not correct

This error usually comes up if you are passing a non serializable value like a fn, class instance or promise in your state. You might need to return values in your mock function so that they get passed in state or parse the testBlob. Since you have not provided the min reproducible code it's not clear to me what is happening on click of button.
